# Is there a way to recover an entire website from the wayback machine?

Tags: download, web, hosting, webarchive

My website files got corrupted and lost all the backup files somehow. Can any one please suggest the process to download entire site.

Its a simple html site. Once after downloading how can I host it ? 
Please help

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a regular crawler because the contents served have the original links, so you get out of the first page immediately when you're crawling it if you don't rewrite the links: in the browser they are rewritten with a client-side script to point back to the Wayback Machine.

If it's simple html, like you mentioned, and very small you might want to save the pages manually or even copy the contents by hand to a new website structure. If it's not small, then try the tools mentioned in the answers to this similar question in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/828907/how-to-download-a-website-from-the-archive-org-wayback-machine

After downloading it you may have to check the structure of the files downloaded for links that may have been incorrectly rewritten or for missing files. The links that point to files that belong to the website should be local links and not external ones. Then you can host it again on a web hosting service of your preference.